# Why I get "emergency stop" for simplest template in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: errors, texniccenter, miktex2.9, compilation-error

I'm newbie in LaTeX and sorry for silly question from my side. I'm using **TeXnicCenter** compiler and always get "emergency stop" for every template I've downloaded. what's wrong with that?

what's the best compiler for LaTeX so that I can always see the output? Any recommendations?

```latex
%======================================================================
%   Titelseite 
%======================================================================
%   $Date:$
%   $Revision:$
%   Matthias Kupfer
%======================================================================

%%======================================================================
%% Schmutztitel
%%======================================================================
%\extratitle{
%   \usekomafont{sectioning}\mdseries 
%   \begin{center}
%       \Huge \dcsubject\\[1.5ex]
%       \hrule
%       \vspace*{\fill}
%       \includegraphics{TUC_deutsch_einzeile_CMYK}
%   \end{center}
%}

%%======================================================================
%% Titelkopf
%%======================================================================
\titlehead{
    \vspace*{-1.5cm}
    % Schriftfamilie wie alle Überschriften, aber nicht fett
    \usekomafont{disposition}\mdseries 
    \begin{center}
        \raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[scale=1.4]{TUC_deutsch_einzeile_CMYK}}\\
        \hrulefill \\[1em]
        {\Large\dcdepart}\\[0.5em] 
        \dcprof
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{1.5cm}
}

%%======================================================================
%% Subjekt
%%======================================================================
\subject{\bf\Huge\dcsubject}


%%======================================================================
%% Titel
%%======================================================================
\title{\sf\Large
    \dctitle
    \\
    \dcsubtitle
}

%%======================================================================
%% Autor des Dokumentes
%%======================================================================
\author{\dcauthorfirstname~\dcauthorlastname}

%%======================================================================
%% Ort, Datum
%%======================================================================
\date{\dcplace, den \dcdate
}

%%======================================================================
%% Publishers
%%======================================================================
\publishers{
    {\parbox{\textwidth-8em}{
        \begin{tabbing}
            {\bf Betreuer:}\quad\=\kill
            {\bf Prüfer:}   \>\dcpruefer\\
            {\bf Betreuer:} \>\dcadvisor
        \end{tabbing}   
    }}
}

%%======================================================================
%% bibliografische Angaben
%%======================================================================
\lowertitleback{
\textbf{\dcauthorlastname, \dcauthorfirstname}\\
\dctitle\\
\dcsubject,~\dcdepart\\
\dcuni,~\ifcase\month\or
  Januar\or Februar\or März\or April\or Mai\or Juni\or
    Juli\or August\or September\or Oktober\or November\or Dezember\fi
    ~\number\year
}

%%======================================================================
%% maketitle
%%======================================================================

\maketitle

%%======================================================================
%% Danksagung
%%======================================================================
\thispagestyle{empty}
\null\vfil
\begin{center}
\usekomafont{disposition}\textbf{Danksagung}
\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\parsep}
%%
%% Hier steht der Text für die Danksagung
%%
\end{center}
\par\vfil\null
\cleardoubleemptypage

%%======================================================================
%%      Kurzfassung / Abstract
%%======================================================================
\def\abstractname{Abstract}     % Wenn der Text "Zusammenfassung" erscheinen 
                % soll, dann muß dies auskommentiert werden

\begin{abstract}
%%
%% Inhalt der Arbeit
%%
\end{abstract}

%%======================================================================
%%      Inhaltsverzeichnis
%%======================================================================
\cleardoubleemptypage
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\pdfbookmark{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents

%%======================================================================
%%      Abbildungsverzeichnis
%%======================================================================
\cleardoublepage
\markboth{Abbildungsverzeichnis}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures

%%======================================================================
%%      Tabellenverzeichnis
%%======================================================================
\cleardoublepage
\markboth{Tabellenverzeichnis}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\listoftables

%%======================================================================
%%      Algorithmenverzeichnis
%%======================================================================
%\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Algorithmenverzeichnis}
%\cleardoublepage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Algorithmenverzeichnis}
%\listofalgorithms

%%======================================================================
%%      Abkuerzungsverzeichnis
%%======================================================================
%\cleardoublepage
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
%\markboth{Abk"urzungsverzeichnis}{Abk"urzungsverzeichnis}
%\def\listacronymname{Abk"urzungsverzeichnis}
%\printglosstex(acr)

%%======================================================================
%%      Ende
%%======================================================================
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

following is error part:

[image: img]

[image: img]

[image: img]

I've used this [template](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DeYPhGZ19IURrDKswbZ8P9x35n03NUBP/view?usp=sharing) for example!

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain answer of question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code fragment you posted is not complete, lacking `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` among other things. This makes it hard to figure out what went wrong. One possibility for the problem might be a missing or malformed `\end{document}`, which would cause tex to try to get more input from the terminal. But not *having* a terminal can result in an emergency stop instead.

Comment: the file you give to latex should start `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}` also, but unrelated, you have an old 2015 format so you should update miktex.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen sir I've added those but still didn't work! I'm gonna upload the layout here you may help me out better!

Comment: Is the version of `ntnuthesis.cls` you're using the same as at https://github.com/COPCSE-NTNU/master-theses-NTNU/blob/master/ntnuthesis/ntnuthesis.cls ?

Comment: @Mico I'm not sure , why are you asking for?

Comment: @Mario - I asked because you have not, so far, provided a link to the document class file `ntnuthesis.cls`, which is used by the [template](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DeYPhGZ19IURrDKswbZ8P9x35n03NUBP/view) you employ.

Comment: @Mico I've checked from website of our uni and I haven't found `.cls` file in the recommended LaTeX package ! Is it necessary? what's that exactly this document class file ?

Comment: The example file given is not the template file e.g. see vorlage.ps as generated via KomaScript (see the readme which I can't translate well enough to give exact instructions but requires running the make file after other versioned edits) I guess you could try TeXing vorlage.tex which uses the {scrreprt} class but that's only part of the 14 interrelated files from https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/urz/software/data/vorlage/

Comment: @KJO man thanks for your consideration I checked and try to run it but still get error like missing `\begin{document}` while there is ! and another emergency stop error! check the [pic](https://i.imgur.com/seiwclX.jpg) BTW: you found my uni quickly :D there might be update problem since it always compiles unsuccessfully by stop emergency error

Comment: Mario I do not know how that template is to be used I have not bothered to test it since it is "not normal" I take your word it will not work you need guidance from those who have used it ( the uni staff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example file given is not the template the template file is vorlage.ps as generated via KomaScript (see the readme which I can't translate well enough to give exact instructions but requires running the make file after other versioned edits)

I did not follow whatever the readme advises users to do so as to update
however FORCE TeXing vorlage.tex which uses the scrreprt class I get dozens of warnings that this template is wildly out of date and not to be trusted. These issues need to be raised with the template maintainers.

[image]

PS the content across 16 atypical pages is not that complex although **the first 47 lines of the template spread out describing the single line of \documentclass[options]** !!
It could probably be achieved much much simpler by starting with an empty file and cut past the working structures. However I would not wish to have to be the one to re-assemble in a foreign tongue.

Comment: The interesting point is you could compile it considering bunch of warings at least but up to me I can't even compile it due to being out of date of TeXnicCenter. I opened the Readme file by editor but there I didn't find helpful instructions except how you extract the package .gz and after that I will have `'vorlage.ps'` but since I use Windows probably i just should use `vorlage.tex` and if newer versions of KOMAscript exist we should change them to `'\ usekomafont {sectioning}'` and `'\ usekomafont {disposition}'` . Do you think can I fix it with minimum changes? BTW: vorlage means template

Comment: Agreed I am using yesterdays updated MiKTeX and forced the simple included TeXworks editor to ignore the constant failures So TeXnicCenter is probably just trying to protect you from background problems in fact your much older pdfLaTeX **"should"** in theory have been better suited to an old template, the problem can be that MiKTeX is too old to retrospectively backdate any necessary historic updates, Also for that mater it would NOT be a good idea to try working with a full earlier 2000 version of TeX Live. I suggest faculty staff are there to assist or find a peer that got through any issues

Comment: Alright, thanks for your effort to help me for troubleshooting , I will contact with university staff.

Answer (score 3):

In German: **Zunächst einmal: Tief durchatmen! ;-)**

The issue here is divided in two parts:

1. You are using an very outdated version of MiKTeX: ...16, the current one is .20: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.4.12)`. That means that it is possible that you **can not compile** your given code, if that codes uses newer command not available in your outdated version!
2. The used KOMA-Script class `scrreprt` is called with options which are outdated. See the relevant warnings for example:

   ```
   Class scrreprt Warning: You've used obsolete option `footnosepline'.
   (scrreprt)              Usage of this option indicates an old document
   (scrreprt)              and changes compatibility level using
   (scrreprt)              `footsepline=false,version=first,
   (scrreprt)              enabledeprecatedfontcommands' that may result
   (scrreprt)              in further warnings.
   (scrreprt)              If you don't want this, you should simply
   (scrreprt)              replace option `footnosepline' by `footsepline=false'.

   Class scrreprt Info: Switching compatibility level to `first'.
   ```

   That means that the complete file `vorlage.tex` has to be reworked to fit the current version of KOMA-Script. That should be the work of the maintainer of that template for uni chemnitz ...
   The next problem in `vorlage.tex` is the usage of outdated packages, for example

   ```
   \usepackage{ae,aecompl}
   ```

   which are simply obsolute or package `scrpage2`, which is a  obsolete KOMA-Script package, instead you should use `scrlayer-scrpage`.
   Nowadays the current encoding is utf-8 (and is used automaticly), your `vorlage.tex` uses `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` ...

The issue has nothing to do with an outdated editor TeXnicCenter as you can see here:

[image: texniccenter]

the issue is only your outdated MiKTeX version and the outdated template ...

So you have only the following possibilitys:

1. Update your used MiKTeX. I recommend you install a completly new version (delete the old one) because there could be problems updating such an oldtimer ... Install the complete MiKTeX (use netinstaller)!
2. Depending on your used version of TeXnicCenter you can install the current version of it 2.02
3. copy the complete content of file `vorlage.zip` into a new directory and compile `vorlage.tex`. It should result in the image I showed above ...

That is the way you can get this template to compile, but to be honest: **I would not use it!** It is simply too old. You will see more problems related to the old version soon.

Better ask your professor for a better template (if he had one) or start writing with class `scrreprt` and add only what you need. That has the advantage that you really understood what you are doing in your document. Please read the documentation of KOMA-Script, if installed type `texdoc scrguide.pdf` on your terminal/console.

And of course can you ask questions here (please always with short compilable code resulting in your issue)!

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation and clarification ! I would like to upvote your answer if I had enough reputation.